# accessing hidden element from iframe when page submited

Tags: javascript, forms, hidden-field

I have a question like this. I have 2 pages in my web for example and page 1 when submited goes to page 2, and of course with it all its html form elements. My question here is  i have an iframe in page1 so how to i send the hidden elements from the iframe to page 2 when( page1 is submited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this script

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

 function fun(iframeid,iframename){
  obj=document.getElementById(iframeid);
   if (obj.tagName=='IFRAME'){
   obj=window.frames[iframename].document.getElementId('myfield1ID').value;

  }
 }
 </script>
```

and then put the values in page1 hidden element and submit the page...

before the end of script

```
         document.getElementById('page1hiden').value=obj.value;
```

this script functiopn you must call it when presing the button to submit the page 1 to p2